# CloudFront does not append all headers

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I'm in a tricky situation that I don't know what to do...

time to time, and in random image files, CloudFront request does not send all headers that are setup in S3, here's the example:

[image]

though in S3 there's a customer header with `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000` CloudFlare hit does not output that header, making Google Inspector complaining about it and our clients blaming us for it :/

This is random, if I invalidate the cache on that file key, it outputs the correct headers **until next time**...

Is there a way to make sure all customer headers in S3 are part of the distribution? And why so randomly?

We have around 20 images for this endpoint, and this only happens some of the times, and in random files.

---

**Updated April 26th**

```
$ curl -D -https://assets.sitecampaign.quantads.com/billigvvs/resources/ab_basket/mobile/close_x.png
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/2 200
content-type: image/png
content-length: 1487
date: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 07:26:28 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 08:48:54 GMT
etag: "7aaf1cfe18a75525238481734a07ba09"
accept-ranges: bytes
server: AmazonS3
age: 242
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 1fcad26913988e10fd175698baa6f474.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: FrSzq4ps96bjEsv0VQ67jwHgf7iTwSP2EczMdH-IYWrAYAxQ8O7Hpg==
```

in Postman:

[image]

In S3

[image]

---

**Updated April 27th**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screen shots appear to be from February, and the `Age` header value seems impossible, particularly if you did an invalidation previously.  Remember that an invalidation needs the path requested by the browser, not the path in the bucket, and invalidation of nonexistent objects still succeed.  Is this screen shot recent?  Fetching the same object, I see the `Last-Modified` header set to `Tue, 03 Apr 2018 06:39:45 GMT` and the `Cache-Control` header is present.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the image was taken last week, why do you say February? Why would I post very old data in a question that I have an issue, is not that I have 100 reputation points... you need to fetch the object through CDN to get the issue, and the biggest problem is that is random, today could be one that image, in 5 days or so could be another... soon I invalidate the link, all goes well again on those objects, I could easily make a Lambda to invalidate the entire "folder" but that I will still not know what's going on.. :/

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added the issue as got it toda, in other **random** file

Comment: You don't have any Lambda@Edge triggers on this CloudFront distribution... correct?

Comment: no, that CDN distribution is hooked up to an S3 bucket/folder as plain as it can be ... I'll link the definitions.